# Unique() function in R

Tags: r

data_state is a variable that I extracted the column State  of the Outcome dataset. So, data_state is vector of state names including "SC".

When I execute `"SC" %in% data_state`, it returns FALSE, which should be TRUE.

Anyone could help me solve the problem? Thanks.

```
data_state <- unique(outcome["State"])
"SC" %in% data_state
```

Comment: can you elaborate more and give some input examples?

Comment: Can you please edit the question with the output of `dput(data_state)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two suggestions to check, even if your question says this is not the case:

1) Should it be `data_state <- unique(outcome[,"State"])`, i.e. with comma?

2) Maybe `data_state` is a factor?

Comment: no, she says it's a vector :)

Comment: `outcome` is likely a dataframe though. And then I can never remember whether `[` returns a vector or a one-column df, instead of `$` which returns a vector.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of `%in%`is to check if a list or a vector contains an item of a certain value.

What you want here is `grepl` :

```
grepl("SC","SC_Sometghing") # TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `outcome` is a data frame, `data_state` will actually be a data frame, not a vector. So you would need to reference `data_state$State` rather than `data_state` after the `%in%` operator.

```
> outcome=data.frame(State=c('SC','NC','MI','CA'), outcome=c(1,1,0,0))
> outcome
  State outcome
1    SC       1
2    NC       1
3    MI       0
4    CA       0
> data_state <- unique(outcome["State"])
> "SC" %in% data_state$State
[1] TRUE
```